# Seleccionar contenido de un TextField al ganar el Foco

Tags: javafx

Quiero que cuando un control `TextField` gane el foco quede seleccionado su contenido. De momento solo aparece el cursor allá donde pulso con el ratón y desaparece la selección. He probado con este código:

```
miTextField.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> 
    observable, Boolean valorAnterior, Boolean valorActual) -> {
    if (valorActual){   
         miTextField.selectAll();        
    }        
});
```

Sustituyendo `miTextField.selectAll()` por `miTextField.selectRange(0, miTextField.getText().length())` tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`selectAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectAll--) debe funcionar, sin embargo se tiene que hacer uso de [Plaform.Runlater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) para que funcione como lo deseas:

```
    miTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean valorAnterior, Boolean valorActual)
        {

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (miTextField.isFocused() && !miTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        miTextField.selectAll();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: Me parece que debes usar también Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { para el primer ejemplo ya que en realidad realiza una operación en la UI, voy a editar mi respuesta.

Answer (score -2):

Más fácil, usa estos dos métodos y lo que haya en el `JTextField` aparecerá seleccionado.

```
miTextField.selectAll();
miTextField.getSelectedText();
```

puedes meterlos en un `event mousecliked` o algo que le indique que cuando gane el foco ejecute estos dos métodos